# Automatically trigger touchstart and touchend using element id

Tags: javascript, html

I have html buttons with individual id's. My need is to trigger 'touchstart' and 'touchend' on each button after some time delay. Is it possible? Otherwise I'll have to rewrite a lot of javascript code.

I have googled but I didn't get any hint.

Comment: Only as a part of user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Below is code with `touchstart` and `touchend` event listeners for an element. Your post says you have multiple buttons that need event listeners. If they both carry out the same function you can reuse the functions below. Functions `start` and `end` both have `setTimeout` functions which delays the code inside from running for the specified amount of time.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load, false); // event listener for page fully loading

    function load() { // function called when page laods
        var element = document.getElementById("element");

        element.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
        element.addEventListener("touchend", end, false);
    }

    function start(e) { // function passed in event listener with "e" object
        setTimeout(() => {
            // code here
        }, 1000); // waits 1 second (1000ms) to run code
    }

    function end(e) { // function passed in event listener with "e" object
        setTimeout(() => {
            // code here
        }, 1000); // waits 1 second (1000ms) to run code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent):

```js
touchstart.addEventListener('touchstart', () => console.log('touchstart'))
touchend.addEventListener('touchend', () => console.log('touchend'))

setTimeout(() => {
  touchstart.dispatchEvent(new Event('touchstart'));
  touchend.dispatchEvent(new Event('touchend'));
}, 1000)
```

```html
<button id="touchstart">touchstart</button>
<button id="touchend">touchend</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do rewrite your code so that you don't have to trigger such events.

My guess is that you have put some business logic (i.e. code that does something relevant for your app) directly inside event listeners, and now you realized that you need to reuse the same logic in a different situation.

If that's the case, the correct thing to do is *not* to try to figure out how to trigger events from code, but instead to extract the logic into separate, reusable functions, that you can then call both from the event listeners and also from a `setTimeout` or similar.